# Trying to get following element (text) without class tag etc

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, parsing

Here's html code of page I'm trying to parse. (Its a bookstore)
[Part of the page code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUtwq.png)

```
<tr><tr>
<tr><tr>
<tr><tr>
<tr><tr>
<tr><tr>
<tr>
    <td width="300" class="highlight">
        <b>Издатель:</b>
         Додо Пресс,Фантом Пресс 
    </td>
</tr>
<tr><tr>
<tr><tr>
<tr><tr>
```

I need to get text that is following

`<b>Издатель:</b>` (translation - Publisher)

First i used `nextsibling` from BeautifulSoup, it worked fine, but on other books' pages on the same site publisher element is't always in the same place which means my chain of next siblings doesn't get the right part of book description.

I tried to locate the exact text 'Издатель:' with Selenium

```
pubs = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Издатель:']")
```

and it did the job. I got the text 'Издатель:'. After that i tried to locate next element following 'Издатель:' because the text that i need is always located after 'Издатель:'.

`followingsibling` form Selenium doest work because publishers' name doesn't have class or tag etc.

I also tried running JS

```
pubs = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Издатель:']")
pub = driver.execute_script("""
    return arguments[0].nextElement""", pubs)
```

```
pub = driver.execute_script("return document.evaluate('// [text()='Издатель:']/following-sibling::text()[1]'), document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue.textContent;")
```

Also didn't work.

Publisher element doesn't have any sibling or child element so i don't know how to get the text following it.

Site URL -  https://www.bgshop.ru/Catalog/GetFullDescription?id=10652263&type=1

Comment: So did you want Dodo Press, Phantom Press? Try something like //td[.//b[.='Издатель:']]/text() as an xpath.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan yes. that's right

Comment: As you mentioned _<b>Издатель:</b> (translation - Publisher)_, what is the other element (in English) you are looking for?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan i got this error selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//td[.//b[.='Издатель:']]/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Comment: You want _Додо Пресс,Фантом Пресс_?

Comment: @DebanjanB I need to get the actual publishers name which is Додо Прнсс, Фонтом Пресс

Answer (score 1):

The text *Додо Пресс,Фантом Пресс* is within a *Text Node* so you have to use *`execute_script()`* inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.bgshop.ru/Catalog/GetFullDescription?id=10652263&type=1")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.collapsed"))).click()
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Издатель:']//ancestor::td[1]")))).strip())
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Додо Пресс,Фантом Пресс
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to extract just the number from html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56681073/how-to-extract-just-the-number-from-html/56681829#56681829)
- [How to extract text from webdriver elements found through xpath using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60038708/how-to-extract-text-from-webdriver-elements-found-through-xpath-using-selenium-a/60040625#60040625)
- [How do I use selenium to scrape text from a text node within a class through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64002481/how-do-i-use-selenium-to-scrape-text-from-a-text-node-within-a-class-through-pyt/64007124#64007124)

Comment: //td[.//b[.='Издатель:']] is a td that contains a b with a text I think it's a more bug free way to write the ancestor with a text.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Yup, another possible approach. But I still feel TD containing B which contains a text would be an expensive algorithm which can be optimized by the `ancestor` easily :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the javascript code below. You can select every `b` element and then get its parrent element and access `innerText` property

```js
document.querySelectorAll('b').forEach( element => {
  console.log(element.parentElement.innerText)
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
      <td width="300" class="highlight">
          <b>Publisher:</b>
          name 1
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
      <td width="300" class="highlight">
          <b>Publisher:</b>
          name 2 
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
      <td width="300" class="highlight">
          <b>Publisher:</b>
           name 3 
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If there are other `b` tags then you can check with if statment if the content of `b` is publisher liek below

```js
document.querySelectorAll('b').forEach( element => {
  if(element.innerText == 'Publisher:'){
    console.log(element.parentElement.innerText);
  }
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
      <td width="300" class="highlight">
          <b>Publisher:</b>
          name 1
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
      <td width="300" class="highlight">
          <b>Date:</b>
          Date 1
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
      <td width="300" class="highlight">
          <b>Publisher:</b>
          name 2 
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
      <td width="300" class="highlight">
          <b>Publisher:</b>
           name 3 
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```